# to cut a bread of size l*b into smaller identical pieces such that each piece is a square having maximum possible side length

Tags: c, math

```
int restaurant(int l, int b) {

      int x,min,max,count=0,i;
 
   if(l<=b)           //here assigning min, max lengths of rectangle
  {
    min=l;
    max=b;
  } 
  else 
  {
     min=b;
     max=l;
  }

 int array[max];  

 for(x=1;(x<=min && x*x<=l*b);x++)  // here checking length of square not 
                                    // exceeding min length of rectangle & 
                                    // area of square not exceeding the 
                                    // area of rectangle
 {
    
     if((l*b)%(x*x)==0)              // here checks the x value for which 
                                     // there is no left over in bread, 
                                     // storing that square length in an 
                                     // array
     {
         array[count]=x;
         count++;        
     }

 }

 x=array[0];                                    
 for(i=0;i<=count-1;i++)                  // getting maximum square length 
                                         //  'x' 
 {
   if(array[i]>=x)
   x=array[i];
 }

 return (l*b)/(x*x);                         // returning no. of square for 
                                             // the max. 'x'
```

}

can you explain why this logic doesn't work ?

no. of squares= (l*b)/(x*x)

where x is maximum possible length of a square

Link for the problem is below
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/restaurant/problem

Comment: How would you cut a `2x2` square out of a `1x4` bread?

Comment: I have modified the code, but still its not working in hackerrank

Comment: Next test-case: What is the largest square which can entirely cover a `4x9` rectangle? Both `2x2` and `3x3` squares would fit a few times, but they can't cover the entire rectangle. I suggest, before coding this try to solve your problem with pen+paper for arbitrary rectangles. The coding afterwards should not be difficult.